# How to insert PwnedPasswordsTop100k.txt into MySQL

Tags: mysql

I obtained the PwnedPassword list of the 100K most common passwords from https://www.ncsc.gov.uk/static-assets/documents/PwnedPasswordsTop100k.txt

How can I insert this list into a MySQL table?

Comment: Do you want to add a blacklist of passwords to MySQL?

Comment: You can use PHP script like here: https://phpize.online/?phpses=2626c8d6600623c869ba8c616a028433&sqlses=b9cf05a0813143145660112d07cb3b6b&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: Thanks Slava Rozhnev. That script worked nicely.

Answer (score -2):

Use the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/loading-tables.html

Comment: It could have been nice if you could have provided an example instead of the direct link. Might have been more useful.